# color doesnt change when i try it ti change

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio, web

why does not color of the tag  change,i do not really understand,there is tag "phone", in css i tried to change color, but it didnt worked,sorry for stupid question
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTA0m.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt0uP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxvCF.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sytB.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: It would also be good to include your index.html file. Maybe there is an incorrect use of `class="phone"`. Maybe there are other classes and css styling overriding. You can use `color: black !important`, but that's not preferred. The property color is used for text. In case you want to color a div, use `background-color` as css-property.

Answer (score 1):

CSS Cascades, that is to say, properties are inherited, but what happens when two selectors try to change the same property, like `color`? CSS choses the more specific one. You can read more about CSS specificity, but suffice it to say, the "closer" selector wins. Consider the two following bits of HTML. The first has the color set by the outer `a` tag to blue, and then set to the more specific color. The second one I have flipped the elements around.

```css
.phone {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href=#>
  <div class="phone">
    What Color Should I be?
  </div>
</a>

<br />

<div class="phone">
  <a href=#>
    What Color Should I be?
  </a>
</div>
```

Why this happens is a bit confusing because where does that blue color come from? Well, every browser has a "user agent stylesheet" that injects its own set of styles. In this case, the `a` element (if it has an `href`) gets a blue color set by this stylesheet!

It's like the combined CSS properties affecting the element would look something like this

```
a {
  color: blue;
}

.phone {
  color: black;
}
```

Now, it should be easy to see that there is something overriding the style you are trying to set.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to style an `<a></a>` so as mentioned above you need to check out css specificity

```
<div class="phone">
  <a href="#">8 (800) 775-16-41</a>
</div>
```

css

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.phone {
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The phone must be a `<a href>` tag? If that's the case, try to put this in the css file

```
.phone a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```